# Eureka Seven Ao, Holland's Longboard

Tags: eureka-seven

I have had a question about this series for a while now. In Eureka Seven Ao, in episode 3 at time 19:27 you can see that the Grand Bleu group is attacking a secret. This secret looks almost identical to Holland's longboard that Eureka and Renton rode on. I was wondering if the secrets have a connection to scub coral or human memories, or if this was just an easter egg. If you can explain this I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you very much.